# Control.Capture is always true?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have created a Windows Forms application, but I get strange behaviour from the Capture property of a control.

On a blank form, with a single label called "label1" and the code

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    label1.MouseDown += pictureBox1_MouseDown;
}

void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(label1.Capture);
    label1.Capture = !label1.Capture;
    Debug.WriteLine(label1.Capture);
}
```

I observed, that the first WriteLine always says "True", the second one always says "False" when the button is clicked. Even when clicked multiple times.

The label never reacts to clicks outside its border, not even when I use `label1.Capture = true` instead.

Am I misunderstanding the expected behaviour of the "Capture" property? I expected the initial value to be false, and the label not to react to clicks outside, after the first click I expect the value to be true, and the label to react to all mouse clicks, even outside its borders.

Comment: Using the same event handler for two controls is liable to be confusing.  You certainly get True when you click the Label.  And sure, False when you click the PictureBox.  Winforms uses the Capture property to reliably generate the Click event and turns it on before firing the MouseDown event.  Necessary so the Click event is *not* raised when you release the mouse after dragging it outside of the control's boundary.  Using the Capture property yourself (as in "react to clicks outside") is not likely to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a `MouseDown` event, the `Capture` for the control always set to `true` initially. So normally if you perform a `MouseDown` and then without releasing mouse button move your mouse out of the control and then release mouse button, the `MouseUp` event of the control will be fired.

If you set `Capture` to `false` in `MouseDown`, then the mouse up event of your control will only fire if your mouse is over the control and if you move the mouse out of your control and then release mouse button, the `MouseUp` event of your control will not raise.

Also in `MouseUp` the capture will be released automatically.

For more information take a look at these resources:

- [WmMouseDown](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs.html#eb52ef690de9feb3) method source code
- [WmMouseUp](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs.html#b5fa5fd5c6823eb3) method source code
- [CaptureInternal](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs.html#c0e48fa1d77922b5) proprty source code
- [SetCapture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646262(v=vs.85).aspx) documentations
- [ReleaseCapture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646261(v=vs.85).aspx) documentations

Comment: Thank you. I am coming from WPF where this is handled differently.